# Applescript File vs Alias

Tags: applescript

I have these two Applescript commands in which they both point to the same file

```
alias "Macintosh HD:Users:scott:Dropbox:Downloads:AppleScriptFinderGuide.pdf"
file  "Macintosh HD:Users:scott:Dropbox:Downloads:AppleScriptFinderGuide.pdf"
```

The alias command works just fine.  However the file command does not as it reports this error:  "Can’t get file "Macintosh HD:Users:scott:Dropbox:Downloads:AppleScriptFinderGuide.pdf"."

Any idea why the file command fails?

Thanks in advance, Scott

Comment: shouldn't file get the path with slashes / instead of semi colon : ?

Comment: colons are used for Applescript paths.  I know its very old skool well so is Applescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not referencing the file correctly.

Try

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFile to file "Macintosh HD:Users:scott:Dropbox:Downloads:AppleScriptFinderGuide.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an alias or file *command* - these are *object specifiers*.  AppleScript proper does not recognize a standard file object, although many applications such as the Finder do.

You *can* create a file URL object (similar to a file object) outside of an application context that most apps will recognize:

```
set myFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:scott:Dropbox:Downloads:AppleScriptFinderGuide.pdf" as «class furl»

tell application "Finder"
  reveal myFile
end tell
```

But in general I use aliases everywhere or plain-text HFS path strings, because these can be coerced to anything necessary without having to worry about quoting spaces or special characters.